# Unable to receive data from USB-UART interface

Tags: c, sdk, xilinx, vivado

I am working on **Zynq 702 Evaluation Board** where I am trying to send and receive data using UART interface. My code works fine when I generate the bitstream from Vivado after selecting the Zynq 702 board in project settings but the same code doesn't work when I specify the corresponding part number(**xc7z020clg484-1**) in Vivado and then generate the bitstream. (Need to use part number as I will be using custom boards in the future)

Following is the code snippet for sending data:

```
for (Index = 0; Index < TEST_BUFFER_SIZE; Index++) {
    /* Wait until there is space in TX FIFO */
    while (XUartPs_IsTransmitFull(UartBaseAddress));

    /* Write the byte into the TX FIFO */
    XUartPs_WriteReg(UartBaseAddress, XUARTPS_FIFO_OFFSET,
            SendBuffer[Index]);
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine for both with Zynq Board and when using part number.

However I am unable to receive data from UART using following code. This works perfectly when specifying Zynq Board instead of part number in Vivado:

```
Running = TRUE;
    while (Running) {
        /* Wait until there is data */
        while (!XUartPs_IsReceiveData(UartBaseAddress));  
        while(recvCount<4)
        {
            input.bytes_array[recvCount]=XUartPs_RecvByte(UartBaseAddress);
            recvCount++;
        }
    }
```

The above code is unable to hit the `while(recvCount<4)` code (on debugging) after sending data through UART terminal(when using part number in Vivado). What could be the problem here? Everything in Vivado block design is the same except the specification of board in one case and part number in the other.

Edit: adding main function and corresponding code:

```
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xstatus.h"
#include "xil_types.h"
#include "xil_assert.h"
#include "xuartps_hw.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"
#include "xtime_l.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "xuartps.h"

#define UART_BASEADDR       XPAR_XUARTPS_0_BASEADDR
#define UART_CLOCK_HZ       XPAR_XUARTPS_0_CLOCK_HZ
#define UART_DEVICE_ID      XPAR_XUARTPS_0_DEVICE_ID
#define TEST_BUFFER_SIZE    16

int UartPsEchoExample(u32 UartBaseAddress,u16 DeviceId);

/************************** Variable Definitions ***************************/

XUartPs Uart_Ps;        /* The instance of the UART Driver */
u8 SendBuffer[TEST_BUFFER_SIZE];    /* Buffer for Transmitting Data */

int main(void)
{
    int Status;
    /*
     * Run the Uart Echo example , specify the Base Address that is
     * generated in xparameters.h
     */
    Status = UartPsEchoExample(UART_BASEADDR, UART_DEVICE_ID);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/**
 *
 * This function does a minimal test on the UART device using the hardware
 * interface.
 *
 * @param   UartBaseAddress is the base address of the device
 *
 * @return  XST_SUCCESS if successful, XST_FAILURE if unsuccessful
 *
 * @note        None.
 *
 **************************************************************************/
int UartPsEchoExample(u32 UartBaseAddress,u16 DeviceId)
{
    int Index;
    u32 Running;
    u32 CntrlRegister;
    int Status;

    union {
        float float_variable;
        u8 bytes_array[4];
    } input,output;
    // Overwrite bytes of union with float variable

    int recvCount=0;

    XUartPs_Config *Config;
    /*
     * Initialize the UART driver so that it's ready to use
     * Look up the configuration in the config table and then initialize it.
     */
    Config = XUartPs_LookupConfig(DeviceId);
    if (NULL == Config) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }
    Status = XUartPs_CfgInitialize(&Uart_Ps, Config, Config->BaseAddress);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    XUartPs_SetBaudRate(&Uart_Ps, 115200);

    CntrlRegister = XUartPs_ReadReg(UartBaseAddress, XUARTPS_CR_OFFSET);

    /* Enable TX and RX for the device */
    XUartPs_WriteReg(UartBaseAddress, XUARTPS_CR_OFFSET,
            ((CntrlRegister & ~XUARTPS_CR_EN_DIS_MASK) |
                    XUARTPS_CR_TX_EN | XUARTPS_CR_RX_EN));
    /*
     * Initialize the send buffer bytes with a pattern to send and the
     * the receive buffer bytes to zero
     */
    for (Index = 0; Index < TEST_BUFFER_SIZE; Index++) {
        SendBuffer[Index] = Index + '0';
    }

    /* Send the entire transmit buffer. */
    for (Index = 0; Index < TEST_BUFFER_SIZE; Index++) {
        /* Wait until there is space in TX FIFO */
        while (XUartPs_IsTransmitFull(UartBaseAddress));

        /* Write the byte into the TX FIFO */
        XUartPs_WriteReg(UartBaseAddress, XUARTPS_FIFO_OFFSET,
                SendBuffer[Index]);
    }

    Running = TRUE;
    while (Running) {
        /* Wait until there is data */
        while (!XUartPs_IsReceiveData(UartBaseAddress));
        while(recvCount<4)
        {
            input.bytes_array[recvCount]=XUartPs_RecvByte(UartBaseAddress);
            //XUartPs_Recv(&Uart_Ps, &u.temp_array[recvCount], 1);
            recvCount++;
        }
        recvCount=0;    
    }

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `recvCount` is well initialized to `0`? Is `recvCount` local or global? Can you show us more code (a [MCVE] would be perfect)

Comment: @purplepsycho Yes `recvCount` is initialized to 0 and is a local variable. I'll add some more code for your reference.